# NFS mounting including FQDN Fails

Tags: 22.04, dns, nfs

I'm running into a weird issue with mounting an NFS share on my 22.04.3 Ubuntu box.

When I try to mount the share using the server's FQDN like this:

`sudo mount -t nfs nfsserver01.mydomain.com:/path/to/share /mnt/nfs`

It fails with a "No such file or directory" error. But works, when I use just the server's short name:

`sudo mount -t nfs nfsserver01:/path/to/share /mnt/nfs`

installed nfs version 1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1.2

The machine is domain joined with sssd. Despite removing the search domain when I dig the FQDN name I still get a authoritative response from the domain DNS server

Placing the ip and hostname of the nfs server in /etc/hosts eg.

`10.1.2.5 nfsserver01.mydomain.com` or `10.1.2.5 nfsserver01`
does not correct the issue.

I'm not sure if there is a way to defeat the dns server response or being domain joined is causing the issue. Any input is appreciated.

Requested output:

```
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.5
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.4
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.6
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> nfsserver01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 30031
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nfsserver01. IN A
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 08 19:14:23 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 39
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.5
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.6
nfsserver01.mydomain.com has address 10.1.2.4
; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> nfsserver01.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63356
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nfsserver01.mydomain.com. IN A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nfsserver01.mydomain.com. 3599 IN A 10.1.2.4
nfsserver01.mydomain.com. 3599 IN A 10.1.2.5
nfsserver01.mydomain.com. 3599 IN A 10.1.2.6
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 08 19:14:23 EST 2024
;; MSG SIZE rcvd: 102
user@hostname:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
**~truncated**
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search mydomain.com
```

Comment: You can use `for i in nfsserver01 nfsserver01.mydomain.com ; do ;host $i; dig $i;done;cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Read `man systemd-dnsmasq`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: @waltinator output added